# Is it possible to assign names of these checkboxes dynamically according to the batch in the back end php script?

Tags: javascript, php, html

batch1
                center1    
                center2

```
            center3    <input type="checkbox" name=center$a[] value="3">

            center4    <input type="checkbox" name=center$a[] value="4"><br>

      batch2  <br>
              center1   <input type="checkbox" name=center$a[] value="1">
             center2    <input type="checkbox" name=center$a[] value="2">

             center3    <input type="checkbox" name=center$a[] value="3">

             center4   <input type="checkbox" name=center$a[] value="4"><br>

 batch3       <br>

             center1   <input type="checkbox" name=center$a[] value="1">
             center2   <input type="checkbox" name=center$a[] value="2">

              center3  <input type="checkbox" name=center$a[] value="3">

             center4   <input type="checkbox" name=center$a[] value="4"><br>

   batch4    <br>


           center1     <input type="checkbox" name=center$a[] value="1">
             center2   <input type="checkbox" name=center$a[] value="2">

             center3   <input type="checkbox" name=center$a[] value="3">

             center4   <input type="checkbox" name=center$a[] value="4"><br>

    <input type="submit" name="submit">
        Is it possible to assign names of these checkboxes dynamically according to the batch in the back end php script?
```

I tried using a variable in the name but while receiving values in the backend php script it does not take the variable separately hence I am not able to assign dynamic values according to batch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is is probably because the variables aren't evaluated, try to change the lines like:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="center<?= $a ?>" value="1">
```

Although at this moment you will have everywhere the same variable `$a` assigned - so it should be something more like `name="center<?= $yourArray[$iteration] ?>"` so the names would be unique, or like `name="center[]" id="center<?= $iteration ?>"` depending what you need.

**Update:**
If you want four (or any number) of "batches" of sets the better answer (as noticed Harrie de Laat in the comments below) would be:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="center<?= $a ?>[]" value="1">
```

Of course you'd have to change the `$a` variable with every batch.

Comment: If he wants all his checkboxes in an array it should be
   
`<input type="checkbox" name="center<?= $a[] ?>" value="1">`

Comment: If there shoudl be four sets ("batches") of "center" variables then you are right, as long if he changes the `$a` variable with every batch.